# PayPal IPN stopped working with Tomcat/Open SSL after POODLE update

Tags: java, tomcat, paypal, openssl, paypal-ipn

The PayPal IPN messages stopped coming through after PayPal made a change to cater for the POODLE vulnerability ([link](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Forward/PayPal-Response-to-SSL-3-0-Vulnerability-aka-POODLE/ba-p/891829)).

We are running Java 1.6 and Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal investigated the problem, and here is the response:

> The issue could be related to the web server your using (Tomcat) and
>   the implementation of ciphers in Open SSL 1.0.
>
> When testing your IPN URL using CURL, we are receiving the following
>   error "error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   internal error"
>
> This appears to be an issue with Open SSL 1.0 and Tomcat, as outlined
>   in the following article -
>   http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2012/02/19/tomcat-7-and-curl-ssl23_get_server_hellotlsv1-alert-internal-error/

So we modified our tomcat server.xml to have the following:

```
ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
```

And the PayPal IPNs started working again.